# does storing image tags in sql database pose security risk?

Tags: php, sql, database, image, web

I'm wondering if storing image tags inside with no validation whatsoever is a security risk. One of the commenters stated below that it can be a security threat because of inline javascript. Also for my situation another solution might be to remove all images except the images with the class of "smilyImage". In other words remove all the images like this: `<img src="whatever.png">` and keep the images like this: `<img class="smilyImage" src="smiley.png">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends. If you're letting the user submit the image tag, they *could  for instance* add a JavaScript onClick-event to it, which might cause some problems (if you're not escaping the return values).

All data passed to the database which you don't know exactly what it is *can* be a security risk.

Comment: true I didn't think of inline javascript. Should have though of it. Is there any way to remove those inline scripts?

Comment: What is 'escaping return values'? Tried googling it.

Comment: @user3234267, see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS). In fact, just park yourself at OWASP.org and do some reading about security threats and their rememedies.

Comment: "Escaping return values" is my poor way of saying "escaping special characters within SQL queries". But I would just store the source URL of the image, as Dwight said. That is much simpler and safer.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your SQL queries are escaped correctly (or better yet, you use attribute binding) then there should be no security risk (you're just storing text in a column, effectively).

If your queries are not safe however, you could be opening yourself to an SQL injection.

I would not be storing image tags in the database though, rather just the URL of the image source (which is easily validatable).

Comment: what is attribute binding? Never heard of it. I tried googling it didn't get much.

Comment: @user3234267, it's more commonly called prepared queries with parameters. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: for my situation I think I could give the images I want to keep a class and strip all the other images.